# Taxonomy & Views

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

How can I take a "Content Type" with a "Taxonomy Term" field... and use views to generate a list of content with that term via URL?

I have a content type that has the basics (Title, Body) as well as Taxonomy Term for a Vocabulary & Weight. I want the user to be able to type:

```
http://myip.org/portals/safety
```

This would theoretically generate

1. HTML list of pages
2. "Menu" to be use in a block with a list of safety (or whatever) pages.

I can't seem to figure out where to get the taxonomy/term to work as variables in the View.

Views has the "Taxonomy Term" default view with

```
taxonomy/term/%
taxonomy/term/%/feed
```

I'd like to remove the /%,/%/feed and auto-magically make a taxonomy/term page/menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to views is to use the filter function to get the correct node relations out in the way you want. I had the same problem where I wanted a node of content type "application" with a taxonomy of "approved", "pending", and "denied". The view should get a with a filter of node: type = "applications", based on my example. That will find the right content. I added a base url of applications for the page view. The arguments section is where the taxonomy can be used to filter based on URL.

portals/safety
node type = safety

portals/safety/one
node type = safety
taxonomy: term = one

portals/safety/two
node type = safety
taxonomy: term = two

It might be easier if I just export the view and see if it helps point the way along.

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'Applications';
$view->description = 'List of all applications';
$view->tag = '';
$view->view_php = '';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;
$view->api_version = 2;
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Application List', 'default');
$handler->override_option('fields', array(
  'title' => array(
    'label' => 'Application',
    'alter' => array(
      'alter_text' => 0,
      'text' => '',
      'make_link' => 0,
      'path' => '',
      'link_class' => '',
      'alt' => '',
      'prefix' => '',
      'suffix' => '',
      'target' => '',
      'help' => '',
      'trim' => 0,
      'max_length' => '',
      'word_boundary' => 1,
      'ellipsis' => 1,
      'html' => 0,
      'strip_tags' => 0,
    ),
    'empty' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'empty_zero' => 0,
    'link_to_node' => 1,
    'exclude' => 0,
    'id' => 'title',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'title',
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'override' => array(
      'button' => 'Override',
    ),
  ),
  'name' => array(
    'id' => 'name',
    'table' => 'term_data',
    'field' => 'name',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('arguments', array(
  'name' => array(
    'default_action' => 'ignore',
    'style_plugin' => 'default_summary',
    'style_options' => array(),
    'wildcard' => 'all',
    'wildcard_substitution' => 'All',
    'title' => '%1 Status Application',
    'breadcrumb' => 'Applications',
    'default_argument_type' => 'fixed',
    'default_argument' => '',
    'validate_type' => 'none',
    'validate_fail' => 'not found',
    'glossary' => 0,
    'limit' => '0',
    'case' => 'none',
    'path_case' => 'none',
    'transform_dash' => 0,
    'add_table' => 0,
    'require_value' => 0,
    'id' => 'name',
    'table' => 'term_data',
    'field' => 'name',
    'validate_user_argument_type' => 'uid',
    'validate_user_roles' => array(
      '2' => 0,
      '3' => 0,
      '4' => 0,
    ),
    'relationship' => 'none',
    'default_options_div_prefix' => '',
    'default_argument_fixed' => '',
    'default_argument_user' => 0,
    'default_argument_php' => '',
    'validate_argument_node_type' => array(
      'blog' => 0,
      'poll' => 0,
      'faq' => 0,
      'forum' => 0,
      'application' => 0,
      'page' => 0,
      'story' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_node_access' => 0,
    'validate_argument_nid_type' => 'nid',
    'validate_argument_vocabulary' => array(
      '1' => 0,
      '2' => 0,
      '3' => 0,
      '4' => 0,
    ),
    'validate_argument_type' => 'tid',
    'validate_argument_transform' => 0,
    'validate_user_restrict_roles' => 0,
    'validate_argument_php' => '',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('filters', array(
  'status' => array(
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => '1',
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'status',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'status',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
  'type' => array(
    'operator' => 'in',
    'value' => array(
      'application' => 'application',
    ),
    'group' => '0',
    'exposed' => FALSE,
    'expose' => array(
      'operator' => FALSE,
      'label' => '',
    ),
    'id' => 'type',
    'table' => 'node',
    'field' => 'type',
    'relationship' => 'none',
  ),
));
$handler->override_option('access', array(
  'type' => 'none',
));
$handler->override_option('cache', array(
  'type' => 'time',
  'results_lifespan' => '3600',
  'output_lifespan' => '3600',
));
$handler->override_option('title', 'Applications');
$handler->override_option('style_plugin', 'list');
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->override_option('path', 'applications');
$handler->override_option('menu', array(
  'type' => 'tab',
  'title' => 'Applications',
  'description' => 'Applications',
  'weight' => '0',
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
$handler->override_option('tab_options', array(
  'type' => 'none',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'weight' => 0,
  'name' => 'navigation',
));
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');
$handler->override_option('block_description', 'Applications');
$handler->override_option('block_caching', -1);
```

Comment: I've adjusted this to my "Portals"... and in the test area, when using "safety" contextual it works. The three pages I have as safety pages show up in a list... but when I go to myip.org/portals/safety it just shows a blank page.

Comment: Not sure what I changed... but i got it working! vonderball... follow-up question coming shortly.

Comment: The issue I have atm... is the page version works, but it doesn't work as a block.

Comment: It wouldn't work in blocks because contextual filters rely on the page URL.